# Unable to follow the intuition behind minimum edit distance

Tags: string, nlp

So i just began reading on MED, but am totally unable to follow it.
Suppose I have to convert "WATER" to "ATERW"
Now I can substitute :

```
W->A, A->T, T->E, E->R, R->W
```

Thus total cost = 2+2+2+2+2 =10 (all substitutions)

However that isnt correct I know, it should be like this

```
WATER-
-ATERW
```

Thus total cost here = 1+1 =2 (deletion and insertion)
But then my question is that how does the program know that it shouldnt match `'W'->'A'`, and rather delete `'W'` and match `'ATER'` in both the string ?? How is that intuition/logic inculcated into the program ?

Answer (score 5):

First you should check the wikipedia page about Levenshtein distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

It is just like edit distance, except for the edit cost.

As you can see, to solve this problem you have to build a matrix (it is a dynamic programing approach). Rows represent the source word, columns represent the target word.

First you initialize the matrix with base cases:

- To transform the empty string into an empty string you need 0 operations;
- To transform the empty string into A you need 1 operation (insertion);
- To transform the empty string into AT you need 2 operations (insertion);
- To transform the empty string into ATE you need 3 operations (insertion);
- and so on...
- To transform W into an empty string you need 1 operation (deletion);
- To transform WA into an empty string you need 2 operations (deletion);
- To transform WAT into an empty string you need 3 operations (deletion);
- and so on...

Now you got your first row and your first column.

```
  _ A T E R W
_ 0 1 2 3 4 5
W 1 ? ? ? ? ?
A 2 ? ? ? ? ?
T 3 ? ? ? ? ?
E 4 ? ? ? ? ?
R 5 ? ? ? ? ?
```

The idea is to fill the matrix cell by cell. The first one to fill is gonna be the cell of the second column of the second row (2,2). It corresponds to the letter W of the source word (ie WATER), and to the letter A of the target word (ATERW).

Let's take a look at the value around and let's add an edit cost to each of these values. We'll then pick the minimum.
For an insertion (left cell) or a deletion (upper cell) the edit cost is always 1. For a substitution (upper-left cell) the edit cost is 1 if the letters are different, 0 otherwise.

We have:

- INSERTION (from cell 2,1): 1 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost);
- SUBSTITUTION (from cell 1,1): 0 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost for different letters);
- DELETION (from cell 1,2): 1 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost).

Now pick the minimum value: 1 (SUBSTITUTION). Cell 2,2 as now value 1.

```
  _ A T E R W
_ 0 1 2 3 4 5
W 1 1 ? ? ? ?
A 2 ? ? ? ? ?
T 3 ? ? ? ? ?
E 4 ? ? ? ? ?
R 5 ? ? ? ? ?
```

Now let's do the same for cell 2,3. It corresponds to the later W of the source word (ie WATER), and to the letter T of the target word (ATERW).

We have:

- INSERTION (from cell 2,2): 1 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost);
- SUBSTITUTION (from cell 1,2): 1 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost for different letters);
- DELETION (from cell 1,3): 2 (cell's value) + 1 (edit cost).

Now pick the minimum value: 2 (INSERTION or SUBSTITUTION). Cell 2,3 as now value 2.

It means that the cost to convert W into AT is 2.

```
  _ A T E R W
_ 0 1 2 3 4 5
W 1 1 2 ? ? ?
A 2 ? ? ? ? ?
T 3 ? ? ? ? ?
E 4 ? ? ? ? ?
R 5 ? ? ? ? ?
```

As you can see we use previous computation (value in cell 2,2) to fill the current cell (2,3). That's the idea of dynamic programming.

Repeat until the matrix is filled. It should looks like this:

```
  _ A T E R W
_ 0 1 2 3 4 5
W 1 1 2 3 4 4
A 2 1 2 3 4 5
T 3 2 1 2 3 4
E 4 3 2 1 2 3
R 5 4 3 2 1 2
```

Take a look at the very last cell (6,6): value is 2. It corresponds to the cost to transform 'WATER' into 'ATERW'.

So as to recover the sequence of edit operations performed you can use a backpointer table. Each row gives, for a given cell, the cell from which you picked the minimum value.

```
2,2 1,1
2,3 2,2
2,4 2,3
2,5 2,4
2,6 1,5
3,2 2,1
...
6,5 5,4
6,6 6,5
```

Now you can parse the table backward and build the path, i.e., (6,6) -> (6,5) -> (5,4)...

Comment: Now to make things clear. The cell from which you pick the minimum value tells you which edit operation to perform: from the left, it is an insertion; from the top it is a deletion; from the top-left, it is a substitution.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Some questions - 1.] So the last cell gives the minimum cost ?   2.] If yes, then how do I find the path to this minimum cost on the matrix. There can be many paths which lead to this minimum cost, which path to take then ?

Comment: 1: yes; 2: yes, there might be more than one path. if you want to recover the sequence of edit operations, you have to build a backpointer table. see my post for an example.

Comment: I made a little mistake in my explanations. it is not [ min(x,y,z) + edit_cost ] but [ min(x+edit_cost,y+edit_cost,z+edit_cost) ]. I am gonna edit my answer to reflect that.