# Correcting repeated letters in user messages

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I try to analyze messages from social media or chats. A common issue is this special kind of misspelling where people use repeated characters to express their emotions or whatever e.g.

```
"wowwwwww!"
"Daaaaaaamn!"
"I'm soooooo pisssssed"
```

I wonder if there is a more or less robust way to correct those cases.

To replace repeated characters (3 repetitions or more) with only two characters, I already found the suitable regex:

```
s = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1\1', s)
```

But given the example above this would result in

```
"woww!"
"Daamn!"
"I'm soo pissed"
```

This looks better, but not yet perfect. How could I decide best when to replace it with one character instead of two?

A (probably naive) approach would be to use a dictionary to check if one version or the other is in the dictionary. Or perhaps are are some rather simple linguistic rules to check when double letters are needed. Or maybe there is a much better way to do this altogether.

EDIT: Based on all the answer I came up with a solution that seems to work not too badly

- Used Ubuntu's `/usr/share/dict/words` as dictionary
- Indexed all dictionary words using `Soundex` (and other similar algorithms)
- For each input word I (a) check if it's in the index, and if not (b) all similar-sounding words and select the one with the highest Levenshtein similarity -- note that, as a preliminary step, replace all 2+ repeated letters with 2 letters
- In the rare case I get multiple top results (e.g., `wooww` results in `wow` and `woo` as equally similar), I exploit the notion of [Typoglycemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typoglycemia) checking the similarity based on the first and last letter

With this solution I not only cover the issue of repeated letters pretty well but also typos in general. It's probably far from perfect, but on the other hand it's a very simple solution.

Comment: ... and that "eats" embedded URL ?

Comment: Will you only be considering English? There are no simple rules, unfortunately - `a` is very rarely doubled, for example, but what if someone is writing about an aardvark? Multiple double letters in a row is rare too, but there's always bookkeeper. English is more exception than rule! The dictionary approach seems a sensible start, although I would still expect the occasional false result (maybe include a way to report when both or neither variant appears).

Comment: The "processed text" has to be displayed or is only for analyzing purpose?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: I already have a reasonably well working tokenizer detecting URLs, email addresses, punctuation (e.g., `Daaaamn...I'm soooo pisssssed!!!!`) and numbers (e.g., `333.222`). So I hope I don't ruin the original message that much.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, rather than an edit to the question - perhaps include the implementation, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the corpus of "misspelled things" is small, maybe provide dedicated rules ?

```
>>> rules = (('wo+w+', 'wow'), ('da+m+n+', 'damn'), ('so+', 'so'),('coo+l+','cool'))
# in "real world", should compile the regex for obvious performance reasons

>>> s = 'wowwww sooo cool'
# in "real world", normalize somehow (lowercase?)

>>> for pattern, replace in rules:
...     s = re.sub(r'\b'+pattern+r'\b', replace, s)
... 
>>> s

'wow so cool'
```

This is highly combinational though ! On the other hand, it might be not too hard to parallelize.

---

For higher performances, maybe write a *lexer*  using [`PLY`](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn3) ? Once again you have to provide dedicated rules for each word, but the main advantage is this time each character will only be examined once. The drawback is you can no longer parallelize easily (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

I post as an other answer, as it is a completely different idea.

If the processed text is only for analyzing purposes, and is not intended to be displayed, maybe you should try to convert to an (approximative) phonetic transcription ?

A [soundex](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52213/)-based algorithm might be a starting point.

Comment: For the time being it's for analyzing messages; no need to display them. I actually thought about replacing all repeated letters with just one (e.g., resulting in `I'm so pised`). I'm just not sure if the number of errors I deliberately generate are at a acceptable level. For example I would change `good` to `god` or `boot` to `bot`.

Comment: I know about Soundex but haven't used it. But I will. It may be even indirectly useful to exploit as index to access a dictionary, i.e., create Soundex of an out-of-vocabulary word and get all similar sounding words from the dictionary.

Comment: @Christian `Soundex` is just an example. This is not necessary the "best" algorithm given your need. I never used it myself, but I used a similar approach if French a very lot time ago. We had some kind of "Movie Database" and we needed to look-up for movies given an actor's name -- regardless of the spelling ("raquel welsh", "rachel welch" "rakelle welsch", ...). It worked pretty well. As about the number of "generated errors" or "false positives", it will all depend on your specified needs.

Comment: I've tried `Soundex`, `NYSIIS, and `Double Metaphone` as provided by [Fuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy). So far, Soundex works best -- with the other two there were strange results for some cases.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a solution using a lexicon and the minimum edit distance (MED).

Let's consider an out-of-vocabulary word: 'daaaaamn'.
The MED from 'daaaamn' to 'damn' is 3 (three deletions).

Now, you can tune up the MED function so as to give a lower cost to deletion.
For example, you can define a cost of 1 for insertion, 1 for substitution, and 0.5 for deletion (now edit distance is 1.5).
Or maybe a cost of 0 for deletion if you already suppressed the same character in a sequence (edit distance is now 1).

Now you just have to pick up the word with the lowest edit distance ('damn' hopefully).

As you you can try many different configurations, you might want to build some reference data and see which solution performs the best.

Good luck.

Recently, I did a post about MED. It's here: [Unable to follow the intuition behind minimum edit distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150440/unable-to-follow-the-intuition-behind-minimum-edit-distance/24151217#24151217)

Comment: Or, in this case, lower the delete cost only when an adjacent letter is the same.

Comment: @Charles Yes, that the idea of my second solution (cost is lowered to 0 here). I think there is plenty of configuration possible. The best thing is to try them out!

Comment: Is there any reason not to change `daaaaamn` to `daamn`, i.e, replacing all 2+ repeated characters to just 2? It seems it would simplify things a bit. But in general, yeah, I will try some kind of dictionary approach.

Comment: @Christian Not sure I get you. You want to replace 'daaaamn' with 'daamn'? that's an unknown word. you need an approach which handles cases where you want to keep only one letter (eg 'damn') and where you want to keep two letters (eg 'cool'). MED + a lexicon allows you to do that.

Comment: @Pierre: I replace `daaaaamn` with `daamn` just as a preliminary step. So I don't have to take care (in the MED that is) how man a's are actually used. Then I have to use a lexicon, you're right.