# Levenshten automata with weights

Tags: c#, nlp, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for an algorithm (and it's implementation on c#) for fast fuzzy string search in a dictionary. So far I found a method called Levenshtein Automata (described [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata)). It seems very simular to what I need. But I would like to give different weights for different errors. Say it's common to confuse `s` and `c` so weight for such an error would be small. Also it would be nice to be able to take into account multiple-letters errors such as  `s` -> `ph` and so on.
It there an algorith described such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Levenshtein automaton matches target strings within a certain edit distance from a source string (i.e. the string used to build the automaton). This is super-fast yet the drawback is that you cannot customize the edit cost (you may want to picture the Levenshtein automaton of a short string, with different edit costs... it's gonna be messy... even for short strings).

Maybe you should consider the well-known dynamic programming approach ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150440/unable-to-follow-the-intuition-behind-minimum-edit-distance/24151217#24151217)), which allows you to define custom edit costs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use the algorith you proposed, but it appeared to be slow for me. Even when I use it with a dictionary prebuilt as a trie.

Comment: or maybe you can use a Levenshtein automaton to filter out some of the words (e.g. those with an edit distance > 3) then process the remaining using the dynamic programming approach...